# Data not showing in jtable using DefaultTableModel on adding as per below code

Tags: java, swing, defaulttablemodel

> Data not showing in `jTable` using `DefaultTableModel` below the code is. here I create >object of `DefaultTableModel` and then set the value to the table model. Values are coming >as i printed them.

```
DefaultTableModel dtm=(DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();

System.out.println("DefaultTableModel--------------"+dtm);

String[] array1=string1.split("!");

try
{
 /* loop for number of rows */
    for(int i=1;i<array1.length;i++) 
    {
        String[] array2=array1[i].toString().split("&"); 

 /* loop for number of columns */
        for(int j=0;j<array2.length;j++)
        {   
            /*values are printing using out.println below*/    
         System.out.println("array2 "+"row- "+i+" column- "+j+"  "+array2[j].toString());
            /*setting value to the default table model object*/
         dtm.setValueAt(array2[j].toString(), i, j);
            //dtm.addRow(new Object[] { array2[0], array2[1], array2[2],array2[3] ,array2[4] });


        }
     }
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
    System.out.println("exception in - "+exception.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: 1) Do you have any exception? 2) What is `string1`? post a [`MCVE`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: No i dont have any exception. and the code is posted is a method body and string1 is String i passed into this method.

Comment: Get rid of your loops and just try `for (String s : array1) {
        dtm.addRow(s.split("&"));
    }`

Comment: here are a few similair questions, there isn't intialited JTable or its model properly, for better help sooner post an SSCCE or MCVE or MCTRE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for String[] array1